# Add spaces and/or breaks in concatenated text from variables of values input fields in jQuery

Tags: jquery, variables, dom, input, concatenation

Trying to get some spaces and/or breaks in the textarea that has its content added dynamically depending on the amount and type of input based o values. All works as it should except the textarea where all the values are added together as a string without having any breaks or spaces. Tried adding divs around each of them but the textarea doesn't allow them and thus doesn't display it.

Hopefully someone can help me further with this. Any help is much appreciated.

html:

```
<select class="categoryName1 changeFields" name="chipsCategory">
    <option value="Category_1">Category 1</option>
    <option value="Category_2">Category 2</option>
    <option value="Category_3">Category 3</option>
</select>

<select class="chipsTaste1 changeFields" name="chipsTaste">
    <option value="brand1">Brand 1</option>
    <option value="brand2">Brand 2</option>
    <option value="brand3">Brand 3</option>
</select>

<textarea id="pasteTotal"></textarea>
```

js:

```
    var allOrders = $('.changeFields').val();

    $('#pasteTotal').append(allOrders);
```

Thank you very much for all possible helps.

Sorry for the big code Dump, and thanks for the help.

Comment: a giant code dump and *fix this for me* is **not** going to get you any help, you need to read [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit this to make it compliant.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson, just thought it could give some clarification in what I am doing. Sorry for that.

Comment: The proper thing is only post code relevant to the issue at hand. A better explanation of the issue as it relates to that code ( or extra comments) also helps. You are free to update your post also any time

Comment: @charlietfl, sorry to you too, thought it was more in the interest of seeing the global picture of what I am doing with the code, thats why I added the large chunk of code, my apologies for that.

Comment: no worries... just filling you in...makes it easier for all of us. Much simpler to read now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In code shown...`$('.changeFields').val()` will only return the value of the first element in the matching selector. You need to loop over all of them if you want the values of all those elements.

You can do this numerous ways such as `$.each` and concatenate strings on each iteration or my preference is to use arrays.

`$.map` creates can be used to map one array into another. In this case it is the array of elements....returning array of values, which can then be joined with whatever delimiter you want

```
var $selects = $('.changeFields').change(function () {
    // make array of the select values
    var allOrders = $.map($selects, function (el) {
        return el.value;
    });
   // join array with comma and space and add to textarea
    $('#pasteTotal').val(allOrders.join(', '));

})
```

I used a `change` handler on the selects to be able to demo the code inside the handler. That code can be adapted to whatever other event code you are currently using

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hcjo9k7n/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: Making an array of it and using the .join method is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for giving me this clear pointers. Cheers.